# How to plot two functions in one plot with different y-axis in Mathematica?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to plot two functions in one plot with one x-axis and two different y-axis. I tried to used the overlay function but the result cannot be satisfied.

```
ZS1 = {{820, 30}, {860, 40}, {880, 50}, {900, 60}, {920, 70}, {930, 
    80}, {940, 90}};
plot1 = ListLinePlot[ZS1, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, 
    ImagePadding -> 25, 
  FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Blue, Automatic, Automatic}]

theta1 = {{980, 0.3}, {960, 0.4}, {920, 0.5}, {880, 0.8}, {800, 
    1.1}};
plot2 = ListLinePlot[theta1, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   ImagePadding -> 25, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> {True, False, False, True}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {All, None}}, 
  FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Red}]

Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished by using the "CombinePlots" function.

```
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][ListLinePlot[ZS1, PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Blue], ListLinePlot[theta1, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Red], "AxesSides" -> "TwoY", FrameLabel -> {Style["Frequency (MHz)", 14], Style["ZS1", 14], None, Style["\[Theta]1", 14]}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]